# Replacing Ubuntu with Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu

I have a Windows XP laptop that I clean install with Ubuntu.
Now I'm trying to go back and clean install the machine with Windows XP.
However, the usual changing boot order to CD-ROM method doesn't seem to work.

It does read the CD but it always gets stuck when trying to find the drive partition.

Please advice.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1. If you currently have a dual-booting Windows/Linux setup.

You use the Windows recovery console.

- Boot from your Windows CD and get
  into the recovery console by pressing
  '**R**' when you get into the setup.
- When the recovery console starts,
  type **fixmbr**. This will clean Grub
  and the Linux MBR.
- Next type **Map** and make a note of
  the HD devices names. One per disk you have.
- Finally type **diskpart /delete [device_name]**
  for each of your HDD drives.
  device_name is obtained from the map
  command above.

Type Exit. You will now be able to install windows normally.

Have fun.

**Important Notes:**

**Note 1**:
diskpart /delete will completely wipe out any partition on that device. So, do not do it for those drives you want to keep the data.

**Note 2**:
 If you have a drive with more than one partition but you wish to wipe just some, but not all, of those partitions, use [partition_name] or [drive_letter] instead of [device_name]. See here for [full diskpart documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415) and don't be afraid to ask if you have any doubts.

### 2. If all you have is Linux installed on your machine

On this case you can't use the recovery console. You need the Linux installation CD.

- Follow the steps delineated at
  Microsoft Support website
  ([KB314458](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314458))

---

### Note on SATA drives:

Older windows XP CDs (before SP1 if my memory serves me right) will not recognize your SATA drives and produce a `Setup did not find any hard disk drives installed in your computer` error message during the early stages of XP Setup. This does not happen with later XP installation CDs, so if you have one of those, use it instead.

- If you don't, read [this article](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/01/21/install-xp-setup-did-not-find-any-hard-disk-drives-installed-in-your-computer/)
  and use a floppy disk.
- If you don't have a floppy disk drive
  (becoming the norm these days), you
  can still deal with this problem. You
  will be using a tool called nLite to
  build your own XP installation CD
  with the SATA drives already in.
  [Instructions here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Install-Windows-XP-On-SATA-Without-a-Floppy-F6-47807.shtml).

I hope this has finally covered all your problems.

All the best.

Comment: Hi A Dwarf, I tried the steps you gave above.
However, I can't even get to the recovery console.

Once I press "R" to get into the recovery console, I get stuck on a screen that says.
"Setup did not find any hard disk drives installed in your computer."
"Make sure any hard disk drives are powered on and properly connected to your computer, and that any disk related hardware configuration is correct. This may involve running a manufacturer-supplied diagnostic or setup process.
"Setup cannot continue. To quit Setup, press F3"

Why is the HD not being recognized?

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: @teepuskin: I completely failed to notice from your initial post that you didn't have any windows partition in your machine. That is why you can use the recovery console. It too needs a Windows partition to be used. For some reason, the words "go back" you used were interpreted by me as "he has windows installed on another partition". My apologies. I'm editing the end of my post to include the information you are after.

Comment: Hi A Dwarf, thanks for the reply. I tried the steps from the Microsoft support website. I was able to use the live CD to delete all the partitions. However, entering the XP CD still gives the same "Setup did not find any hard disk drives installed in your computer."

Now when I just let my computer boot up, I get an error 
GRUB Loading Stage 1.5 GRUB Loading, Please wait... ERROR 22

I suppose that is expected since all partitions are gone.

After that I also tried to make 2 new partitions. EXT3 and FAT32 (hoping the FAT32 can be detected). That didn't work too.

Please help.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Your XP CD instalaltion (pre-SP1, I would assume) isn't recognizing your SATA HD. Fixable. I'm adding even more information to my answer in a bit.

Comment: Hi A Dwarf, I finally just got to borrow an XP SP2 CD. Still the same issue with hard drives not found message. This is insane and lots harder than I thought. I'll keep on tinkering in the meantime, but please let me know if you know of other possible cause.
Thanks, Tee

Comment: That is indeed insane :( Please let me know what make and model is your hard drive

Comment: Hi A Dwarf, I finally got it to work now. The all new Windows 7 test CD that I borrow does the trick. Thanks for taking the time. Regards, Tee

Answer (score 0):

In your BIOS, is there an option for "Legacy Mode" or "IDE Mode" for the hard drive? XP doesn't have native AHCI support and finding the driver is sometimes problematic. Setting the SATA operation to IDE/Legacy instead of AHCI often fixes hard drive detection issues.

Comment: Hi MarkM, I don't see that option. All I see is SATA Native Mode that has values of enabled and disabled.
Default was enabled. I tried disabling it and it doesn't work.

Thanks,
Tee